# How do i plot new projectile with new input?

Tags: javascript, html

I've run into a problem and haven't been able to find a answer yet.Saw some similar questions but still dont quite get it. I have this  projectile trajectory simulator but when i input new value of angle or speed into input field trajectory doesnt change.How can i make it use the value i input and not the default one?

```
<html> 
    <head>              
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <div id="wrap">  
        <canvas id="surface" width="800" height="400"></canvas>         
        <nav> 
            <label for="angle">Angle</label> 
            <input name="angle" type="text" id="angle" value="45" placeholder="angle" oninput="start()"/> 
            <label for="velocity">Speed</label> 
            <input type="text" name="velocity" id="vel" value="45" placeholder="velocity" oninput="start()"/> 
            <input type="reset" value="Launch" onclick="start()">
        </nav>                  
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var b=document.getElementById('angle').value;
            var o=document.getElementById('vel').value;
            var pro = {
                x:50,
                y:380,
                r:15,
                v:o,
                theta:b,
                };              
                var canvas = document.getElementById('surface');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');              
                var frameCount = 0;
                var v0x = pro.v * Math.cos(pro.theta * Math.PI/180);
                var v0y = pro.v * Math.sin(pro.theta * Math.PI/180);
                var startX = pro.x;
                var startY = pro.y;
                var g = 9.8;
                setInterval(function()
                {
                    ctx.save();
                        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(256, 256, 256, .3)";
                        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    ctx.restore();                  
                    if(pro.y<canvas.height - pro.r && pro.x < canvas.width - pro.r)
                    {
                        pro.y = startY - ( v0y * frameCount - (1/2 * g * Math.pow(frameCount,2)) );
                        pro.x = startX + v0x * frameCount;
                    }                       
                    ctx.save();
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.9)";
                        ctx.arc(pro.x,pro.y,pro.r,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                        ctx.fill();
                        ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.restore();
                    frameCount+=.1;                     
                }, 1000 / 77);              
            function start()
            {
                pro.x = 50;
                pro.y = 380;
                pro.v = o;
                pro.theta = b;
                frameCount = 0;
                v0x = pro.v * Math.cos(pro.theta * Math.PI/180);
                v0y = pro.v * Math.sin(pro.theta * Math.PI/180);
            }
        </script> 
    </div>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short answer:
replace

```
var b=document.getElementById('angle').value;
var o=document.getElementById('vel').value;
```

with

```
var b=document.getElementById('angle');
var o=document.getElementById('vel');
```

and `b` and and `o` with `b.value` and `o.value`

A longer answer:
There are 2 data types in JavaScript: primitive and reference. When you write *a=b*, you will get an exact copy of *b* if *b* is of a primitive type (number, string, boolean, null or undefined), but if *b* is of a reference type (array, function or object) your *a* will be just a link to the same object as *b* and modifying one will modify another. You can think of it as buying a book vs buying a subscription to an on-line course. If the content of the course changes, your book will not reflect it, but if you have a link to it, you will be able to see the update. `var b=document.getElementById('angle').value;` is equivalent of buying a book, while `var b=document.getElementById('angle');` will get you a link to the DOM object.

```js
var b=document.getElementById('angle');
            var o=document.getElementById('vel');
            var pro = {
                x:50,
                y:380,
                r:15,
                v:o.value,
                theta:b.value,
                };              
                var canvas = document.getElementById('surface');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');              
                var frameCount = 0;
                var v0x = pro.v * Math.cos(pro.theta * Math.PI/180);
                var v0y = pro.v * Math.sin(pro.theta * Math.PI/180);
                var startX = pro.x;
                var startY = pro.y;
                var g = 9.8;
                setInterval(function()
                {
                    ctx.save();
                        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(256, 256, 256, .3)";
                        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    ctx.restore();                  
                    if(pro.y<canvas.height - pro.r && pro.x < canvas.width - pro.r)
                    {
                        pro.y = startY - ( v0y * frameCount - (1/2 * g * Math.pow(frameCount,2)) );
                        pro.x = startX + v0x * frameCount;
                    }                       
                    ctx.save();
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.9)";
                        ctx.arc(pro.x,pro.y,pro.r,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                        ctx.fill();
                        ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.restore();
                    frameCount+=.1;                     
                }, 1000 / 77);              
            function start()
            {
                pro.x = 50;
                pro.y = 380;
                pro.v = o.value;
                pro.theta = b.value;
                frameCount = 0;
                v0x = pro.v * Math.cos(pro.theta * Math.PI/180);
                v0y = pro.v * Math.sin(pro.theta * Math.PI/180);
            }
```

```html
<canvas id="surface" width="800" height="400"></canvas>         
        <nav> 
            <label for="angle">Angle</label> 
            <input name="angle" type="text" id="angle" value="45" placeholder="angle" oninput="start()"/> 
            <label for="velocity">Speed</label> 
            <input type="text" name="velocity" id="vel" value="45" placeholder="velocity" oninput="start()"/> 
            <input type="reset" value="Launch" onclick="start()">
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not resetting the values of variables `b` and `o` when you call `start()`, so they will always stay the same.

Stick these at the beginning of `start()`:

```
b=parseFloat(document.getElementById('angle').value);
o=parseFloat(document.getElementById('vel').value);
```